# How can I use wildcards or regular expressions to control Path-based authorization / access control for svn?

Tags: svn, svn-hooks, svn-administraton

Is there a way to control view/read access to svn using path-based authorization which relies on regular expressions or wildcards?

I know I can use [svnperms](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/tools/hook-scripts/svnperms.py) to control write access via commit hook script but I need to limit read/view access as well and at present I have a project root with commit files to which all people need access and sub directories to which only specific people should have access.  Granting access to the top level project dir automatically grants it to all subdirectories.  If I could set up a regex rule I could easily limit the access.

If I can't find a way to control the access via wildcard or patterns that I'll need to refactor the directory structure to move the top level files into a subdirectory to which I can set permissions.

Please let me know if you know of either:

- hook script which can control view access
- apache extension that can provide authz capabilities with wildcards or regex patterns

Comment: http://subversion.tigris.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=2662

Answer (score 1):

as of June 2013 it is impossible to do this.  So, the solution to the problem is to re-organize the repository so this isn't necessary.  When a thing is too difficult it usually leads to a large rethink of the design or approach.

At present maven structure leads to this requirement:
root/pom.xml
root/project1/pom.xml
root/project2/pom.xml
etc..

We can replace this with
/root/pom.xml
/project1/pom.xml
/project2/pom.xml
etc..

We can set the svn perms as follows granting all read access to the top level project and read write to their project.  If an continuous integration build server populates an internal maven repo with the root snapshot then the users only need to checkout specific projects.

```
[repo:/root]
* = r
@releng = rw

[repo:/project1]
@teamOne = rw

[repo:/project2]
@teamTwo = rw
```